# Similarity matrix clustering

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, data-analysis

I trying to clustering text data, data is clear, tokenized, etc.
How i can input similarity matrix in Kmeans or other clustering models?

```
from gensim import corpora
from gensim import models
from gensim.models import Word2Vec, WordEmbeddingSimilarityIndex
from gensim.similarities import SoftCosineSimilarity, SparseTermSimilarityMatrix
documents = list(data['clear_response'])
texts = [[text for text in doc.split()] for doc in documents]
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(texts)
bow_corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(doc, allow_update=True) for doc in texts]

tfidf = TfidfModel(dictionary=dictionary)
similarity_index = WordEmbeddingSimilarityIndex(w2v_model.wv)
similarity_matrix = SparseTermSimilarityMatrix(similarity_index, dictionary, tfidf, nonzero_limit=100)
docsim_index = SoftCosineSimilarity(bow_corpus, similarity_matrix, num_best=30)

model_sim = KMeans(n_clusters=10, init='k-means++').fit_predict(similarity_matrix)
clusters_sim = model.sim.labels_.tolist()
clusters_sim

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'SparseTermSimilarityMatrix'
```

Answer (score 4):

Kmeans algorithm requires samples represented in some feature space and not a similarity matrix. If you want to cluster based on a similarity matrix you should look at different algorithms such as:

- MDS (multidimentional scaling) which will embed your points in some feature space based on the similarity matrix.
- Clustering algorithms that cluster based on the similarity matrix such as Neighbor-Joining or UPGMA.
- Clustering algorithms that use the similarity matrix to define connected components such as spectral clustering.

Which is suitable for your needs depends on the properties of your data. Each algorithm assumes different things regarding the data (such as distributions of points in and between clusters).

You can find the following CrossValidation question: [Clustering with a distance matrix](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/2717/214694). It uses a distance matrix but you could transition from a distance to similarity matrix